# What motors, battery and ESC to use for a drone of payload >50kg?

Tags: brushless-motors, lipo-batteries, esc

So I am designing this octocopter which can lift up a payload of more than 50kg, min 50kg for an intra-city package delivery drone. From what I figured, with 8 motors, the safest thrust needed will be 2.2* whole weight of drone / 8 which corresponds to 16500 g of thrust.

I plan to use this motor: http://shop.dualsky.com/ga6000-giant-airplane-series-for-e-conversion-of-gasoline-airplane_p0145.html and from the table in the website, using 44.4V 12S Lipo Battery with a 26x10 inch propeller gives around 16882 g of thrust which will be perfect? Correct me if I am wrong.

The maximum current draw from the motors will be 909.8A ( from the table), however, I am not sure about the optimal battery and ESC to use. I used eCalc to simulate the conditions but never came to the right "green zones" for all parameters. Can you help me as I am a mechanical engineering student but is not quite good at electrical engineering.

Update: I've used a Truningy 150cc Rotomax outrunner brushless motor with 40x10 inch propeller and battery 6000mAh 3S 100/200C. These simulate these parameters but hover flight time will be under 2 minutes [image: I've used a Truningy 150cc Rotomax outrunner brushless motor with 40x10 inch propeller and battery 6000mAh 3S 100/200C. These simulate these parameters but hover flight time will be under 2 minutes]

Comment: Not to be a party pooper, but given your questions and lack of experience with drones, I think you are WAY above your head. Start small, learn, go to the next level.

Comment: Indeed thank you for that.. but I never actually plan to build one. I recognize that to build an actual prototype of this scale would need a team of experts from different proffesionalities. It is design work and this is all for myself to gain experiences in modelling and simulation, and working alongside my friend who’s an aerospace engineering student. However, I want to see what actual components are available to make this drone if it were to be scaled from a smaller size.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of a [Robotics Stack Exchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/20605/37) question, which I have now closed.

Comment: The over 900 A should be a pretty clear indication that you'll need motors and batteries with a lot more voltage to produce that much lift, or you'll also be trying to lift 50 kg of copper to carry all that current around.

Comment: Maybe use diesel engines like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soxxPyaAT1k